# Multiple afterAdd calls in Knockout.Js

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I've started using Knockout.js library recently. I have a grid of items and I'm trying to use the afterAdd property in foreach. The problem is that it calls the afterAdd handler 3 times instead of 1. Is there something wrong or is it the proper behavior of knockout.js (why?)

[Console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvtj.png)

This is the HTML code snippet

```
<tbody id="body_table" data-bind='foreach: { data: items, afterAdd: addSelect2}'>
```

and this is the knockout viewmodel code snippet

```
self.addSelect2 = function(element, index, data) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the intended behaviour, as it is called for each new element in items. The documentation states that `afterAdd` is specifically meant "for triggering animations related to changes in a list" and it "is invoked only when new entries are added to your array".

Read more [here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements).

Seems like you need to create a custom-binding for your requirement.

Comment: Yes, but I'm adding only 1 item, why I see 3 console.logs and not only 1?

Answer (score 0):

if added foreach in the tbody that element will be called three times.

```
between tbody => tr , element.nodeType ==> 3
between tr => /tr , element.nodeType ==> 1
between /tr => /tbody , element.nodeType ==> 3

if (element.nodeType == 1)
```